# Customise Wordpress Comments Form

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to tweak the default Wordpress comments form so that it works along with the Foundation framework.

This is the code I am using inside `functions.php` thus far:

```
function pondera_comment_form() {
    $comment_args = array(
        'title_reply'=>'Have something to say?',
        'fields' => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields',
        array(
            'author' => '<div class="small-12 large-6 columns">' . '<label for="author">' . __( 'First Name' ) . '</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span>*</span>' : '' ) . '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></div>',
            'email'  => '<div class="small-12 large-6 columns">' . '<label for="email">' . __( 'Email Address' ) . '</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span>*</span>' : '' ) . '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' />'.'</div>',
            'url'    => '' )
        ),
        'comment_field' => 
        '<div class="small-12 large-12 columns">' . '<label for="comment">' . __( 'Comments' ) . '</label>' . '<textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea>' .  '</div>',
        'comment_notes_before' => '',
        'comment_notes_after' => '',
    );
    comment_form($comment_args);
}
```

I'm looking for a way to customise the submit button in the same way as some of the other inputs, but I'm unsure how to do this. I want to wrap it in this `<div class="small-12 columns>` as well as adding a `.button` class to the input itself.

I'm also looking to do the same for the `<h3>` title that WP generates.

Comment: don't you have a comments.php file in your theme? if so, then you can modify the form there directly by adding any class that you want to the button so it's styled like foundation. I've modified the comment form like that all the time. This however will depend on how your theme is setup.

Comment: I'm creating the theme from scratch so I can use almost any approach. I do have a comments.php file, currently this outlines the display of the comments themselves and then has a `<?php pondera_comment_form(); ?>` reference to display the form. (This is how I've always done it.) Then I've used the function to tweak the functionality. I didn't realise you can code it all from scratch, is there a resource page to show how to do this correctly?

Comment: I would recommend that you check the whiteboard framework. http://whiteboardframework.com/ The person what wrote this theme has a very nice comments.php template that shows the approach I am suggesting, perhaps this is a good example, let us know if it got you closer to where you wanted to be with this. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I've realised how painfully easy this is within the `comments.php`. Big thanks to @sulfureous for pointing me in the right direction.

For anyone who is interested, here is the code that I placed inside of the `comments.php` (the function referenced originally was subsequently removed):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <?php if(comments_open()) : ?>
            <h3>Have something to say?</h3>
            <form action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="comments-form">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-12 large-6 columns">
                        <label for="author"><?php _e('Name'); ?> <?php if($req) echo "(required)"; ?></label>
                        <input type="text" name="author" id="author" value="<?php echo $comment_author; ?>" size="22" tabindex="1" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-12 large-6 columns">
                        <label for="email"><?php _e('Email'); ?> <?php if($req) echo "(required)"; ?></label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $comment_author_email; ?>" size="22" tabindex="2" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-12 columns">
                        <label for="comment"><?php _e('Comment'); ?></label>
                        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="100%" rows="10" tabindex="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-12 columns">
                        <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="4" class="btn" value="Post Comment" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?>
            </form>
        <?php else : ?>
            <h5><?php _e('Sorry, the comments are now closed.'); ?></h5>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```